# Connection is not available, request timed out

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, hikaricp

Basically we have similar issue mentioned in this thread.
[Gitbhub similar issue disc](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1111)

Versions used:
<hikaricp.version>2.7.6</hikaricp.version>

```
Exception stack trace:
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: 
Unable to acquire JDBC Connection org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: 
Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: 
Unable to acquire JDBC Connection at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:542) at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) 
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:48) at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) 

Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: db-pool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 932300ms. 

at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:548) at 
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:186) 
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: 
Connection timed out (Read failed) at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1667) 
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1654)
```

Database configuration

```
configuration:
public static final int DB_CONN_POOL_SIZE = 50;
public static final int DB_INIT_FAIL_TIME_OUT = 10000;
public static final long CONN_LEAK_THRESHOLD_IN_MILLS = 240000; //4 min
public static final long CONN_IDLE_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLS = 900000; //15 min
public static final long CONN_MAX_LIFE_IN_MILLS = 1800000; //30 min
public static final int CONN_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLS = 10000; //10 sec
public static final int QUERY_TIMEOUT_IN_SECS = 30; //30 secs
config.setMaximumPoolSize(DB_CONN_POOL_SIZE); config.setLeakDetectionThreshold(CONN_LEAK_THRESHOLD_IN_MILLS); //4 mins config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1"); config.setValidationTimeout(CONN_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLS); config.setIdleTimeout(CONN_IDLE_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLS); config.setMaxLifetime(CONN_MAX_LIFE_IN_MILLS); config.setConnectionTimeout(CONN_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLS); //10 secs DataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

To add some more information, we do set 'QUERY_TIMEOUT_IN_SECS ' for most of the read calls and not to the save/update calls.

My question is why connection was released/timed out after 932300ms(15mins) the only correlation i see for this behaviour is 'CONN_IDLE_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLS ' configuration. is it because of this configuration?

I'm enabling the debug logs for hikari cp to check connection leak, just in case if this information helps and someone can throw some light on this topic would be helpful.

Comment: _"Basically we have similar issue mentioned in this thread."_ What thread?

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktrace in a readable manner. The error suggests that you're trying to connect to the wrong port, or a firewall is blocking your connection. Also make sure to provide a [mre].